# Spring Security SSO works only in incognito mode

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, single-sign-on

I've tried to run this tutorial: [Simple Single Sign-On with Spring Security OAuth2](https://www.baeldung.com/sso-spring-security-oauth2), but it works for me only when I use browser in incognito mode (tested with chrome and firefox).

[Source code here](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/spring-security-sso)

Different Spring boot and spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure versions (2.1.1, 2.1,3, 2.0.8) don't change anything.

The only difference in login requests is Cookies.

In incognito:

> Cookie: JSESSIONID=D9037C17D2F5E820B87A20522982935A

Standard mode:

> Cookie: _ga=GA1.1.928100707.1541164056

[Debug logs during login on spring-security-sso-auth-server in standard mode](https://gist.github.com/wirtsleg/f25c070596a0a801d265cdd0f1486e5a)

Full requests screenshots:
[Incognito request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9Cpv.png), 
[Standard request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZ9Aj.png)

**EDIT**:
After reseting to source tutorial version it works fine in Firefox and Opera in any mode. But still works only in incognito in chrome. May be some plugin ruins.

Comment: what is the scope ? what is the session.cookie.name? Is it UISESSION. Could you please share your code here.

Comment: I added link to github tutorial code. My code is almost identical, just changed ports. In tutorial server.session.cookie.name are UISESSION and UI2SESSION. But I found strange that prop names are server.session.cookie.name instead of server.servlet.session.cookie.name. Anyway result is the same. Scope is "user_info".